# SortField in Jooq does not allow sorting on fields

Tags: graphql, jooq, graphql-java

So I am trying to code a function which will allow sorting in multiple fields in either ascending or descending order. My code is below

```
 //SortBy
    List<SortField> order = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String field:sortBy) {
        if ((ascending)) {
            order.add(DSL.field(field).asc());
        } else {
            order.add(DSL.field(field).desc());
        }
    }

    return jooq.selectFrom(CAR)
        .orderBy(order.toArray(new SortField[order.size()]))
        .fetchInto(Car.class);
```

The problem is if I give two fields as an input (e.g. [color, year]), it sorts only on second parameter but not on the first one (in both ascending and descending). When I didnt have SortField at all and just used Field, it was working perfectly, albeit just for ascending order

```
 //SortBy
    List<Field> order = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String field:sortBy) {
        if ((ascending)) {
            order.add(DSL.field(field));
        } else {
            order.add(DSL.field(field));
        }
    }

    return jooq.selectFrom(CAR)
        .orderBy(order.toArray(new Field[order.size()]))
        .fetchInto(Car.class);
```

I have been stuck for a while and cant figure out why this is. Does anyone has any idea?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I can tell your code looks correct. Can you tell us which version of jOOQ you are using? Further, if you haven't explicitly set `Settings.executeLogging` to `false` (or disabled debug logging), you should see some logging which shows exactly what SQL query was executed. Can you verify that this looks correct?